# Windows key authentication in spring-integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, sftp, spring-integration-sftp

I have a windows server from which I need to transfer files to another server with **sftp**. The target server may be a Linux or a windows box.

My question is, do I have to rely on third party sftp server software on my windows machine or does spring integration take care of that?

How should I generate public and private key pairs on windows box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Integration is only an SFTP client - it can send/retrieve files to/from any SFTP server. No additional software is required (it has a transitive dependency on JSch which will be put on the classpath automatically by maven/gradle).

Spring Integration does *not* provide an SFTP server; for the remote windows server, you will need additional software for that.